# This submit event is called continously why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

**this is my cshtml code**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Edit for </h1>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <form method="post" asp-action="editgoal" asp-controller="TimeSheet" id="goalform">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                                <label for="mission">MissionTite</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="goalmission" asp-for="@Model.Item1.missiontitle" readonly />
                                                <span class="text-danger" ></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input id="timesheet" asp-for="@Model.Item1.timesheetid" hidden />
                                          
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-2">
                                                <label for="action">Actions</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="action1" asp-for="@Model.Item1.Action"/>
                                                <span class="text-danger d-none"  id="actionval">Action is required</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                                <textarea id="message1" placeholder="Enter your message" type="text" asp-for="@Model.Item1.Notes"></textarea>
                                                <span class="text-danger d-none" id="messageval">Notes is required</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn apply rounded-pill">Edit</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**now when i click on anchor tag**

```
<a class="nav-link text-black editgoalsheet mx-2"  data-timesheetid="@goal.timesheetid" data-action="@goal.Action"  data-missiontitle="@goal.missiontitle" data-notes="@goal.Notes" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                        <i class="bi bi-pencil-square icon"></i>
                                    </a>
```

**this is my js i called and in this if my message or action is empty than i am showing error message but in this when i write the message than this js is of submit is called continously**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#staticBackdrop').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            alert("modal called");
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
            var timesheetId = button.data('timesheetid'); // Extract missionid from data attribute
            var missionTitle = button.data('missiontitle');
            var notes = button.data('notes');
            var action = button.data('action');
            console.log(action);
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('#goalmission').val(missionTitle);
            modal.find('#action').val(action);
            modal.find('#message').val(notes);
            modal.find('#timesheet').val(timesheetId);
    });
});
$('#goalform').submit(function (event) {
        $('#messageval').addClass('d-none');
    $('#actionval').addClass('d-none');
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#action1').val() == '') {
        console.log("for action", $('#action1').val());
        $('#actionval').removeClass('d-none');
    }
    else if ($('#message1').val() == '') {
        console.log("for message", $('#message1').val());
        $('#messageval').removeClass('d-none');
    }
    else {
        $('#actionval').addClass('d-none');
        $('#messageval').removeClass('d-none');
        $('#goalform').submit();
    }
});
```

**when i write the message than also it is not going in else block why guide me**

Comment: I mean... you call `submit` from inside the submit handler; I don't recall how jQuery submit events work, but that seems bad. For example, see [this "bug" from a decade ago](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7167).